# Computer crashes with second video card enabled

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I recently added a second GTX 570 graphics card to my computer to run a third monitor.  Motherboard is a Gigabyte Z77X-UD3H.  The computer sees the card and the monitor attached to it.  In the display configuration screen, the third monitor is greyed out.  When I click on it or make it active all three screens go black and then the blue computer dump screen comes up and the computer reboots in the original two monitor setup.  Both cards work fine separately and the problem occurs with or without the SLI cable connected.  Help?  Thanks!

Comment: Motherboard firmware updates, check voltage requirements for the cards combined and ensure the motherboard supports that where connected, PSU, etc. Maybe the card needs additional power cable connected when both are running for extra voltage.